# How to using AutoMapper to map a child list object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have 2 objects : Parent and ParentDTO :

```
    public class Parent
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set;}
        public string ParentCode { get; set; }
        public List<Child> ListChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParentDTO
    {
        public int ParentID { get; set; }
        public string ParentCode { get; set; }
        public List<ChildDTO> ListChild { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildDTO
    {
        public int ChildID { get; set; }
        public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to using AutoMapper to map data from Parent object to ParentDTO object (all data in ListChild has to transfer to ListChildDTO)

Can anyone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to just create the top level mappings, and AutoMapper will automatically map the list.

```
//Create Mappings
Mapper.CreateMap<Parent, ParentDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Child, ChildDto>();

//Map
Mapper.Map<Parent, ParentDto>();
```

Check out the Wiki on the AutoMapper project site on GitHub.
http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

Comment: @quangho Can you mark this as the correct answer to help others that may face the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

Before map modify your code like this

```cs
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        this.ListChild = new List<Child>();
    }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentCode { get; set; }
    public List<Child> ListChild { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentDTO
{
    public ParentDTO()
    {
        ListChild = new List<ChildDTO>();
    }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public string ParentCode { get; set; }
    public List<ChildDTO> ListChild { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDTO
{
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public string ChildCode { get; set; }
    public ParentDTO ParentDTO { get; set; }
}
```

Then map